# Open cameras from two different Raspberry Pi in ONE python code

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera

I have two Raspberry Pi 4 B Boards. Every board has a camera connected with the CSI-Port.

Then, there is a third computer (my laptop). This computer is connected to both Raspberrys via Ethernet Gibabit to make the connection via SSH possible. My aim is to get a openCV depth map by capturing images from both Raspberrys.

Is there a way that the third computer (my laptop) executes a python code that opens the cameras of the two raspberries and opens images of both at the same time for calibration?
I mean a possibility to open both cameras in ONE python-code..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could stream both cameras and recieve both streams in one code

Comment: You can either directly connect the camera to your laptop and run the script, or if you definetly want to go with this architechture then it is better to stream the camera feed from each raspberry pi via rtsp and read that in another script (running on your laptop) and proceed with camera calibration.

Comment: If your looking for any rtsp opencv streaming check this github repo https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/OpenCV-rtsp-server

Comment: I will try the stream.. thank you!